# Derive an expression to estimate the total number of clusters N, with unequal cluster sample sizes m

Tags: sample-size, biostatistics, cluster-sample

The task in the question below is to determine the number of clusters required for a "cluster randomised crossover" design conducted over two 6-month periods, with m = subjects per cluster per period, ρ is the correlation between subjects in the same cluster in the same 6-month period, η is the correlation between patients subjects in the same cluster but in different 6 month periods.

[image]